# Why the codomain of the norm function for quadratic integer rings is $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$, but not $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}] = \{ s+t\sqrt{d} : s,t \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ with $d$ square-free and $d \not \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ be a quadratic integer ring. The most usual definition of norm is $N: R \setminus \{ 0 \} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ by setting $s+t\sqrt{d} \mapsto |s^2 - dt^2 |$.

Apparently, if (1) most (all?) definitions require $d$ be squared-free and (2) $N(0)$ is undefined, then $N(s+t\sqrt{d})$  can't be zero. Why the codomain of $N$ is $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$, but not $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$?

Comment: Is this (including the absolute value) really the most usual definition of the norm? I would have thought that since the field norm $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})^\times \to \mathbb{Q}^\times$ is given by $s+t\sqrt{d}\mapsto (s+t\sqrt{d})(s-t\sqrt{d}) = s^2-dt^2$ we would get $N:R\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ by restriction

Answer (score 2):

It's honestly not important and you shouldn't waste too much thought on it.

If you're really interested in details though, here they are:

- Despite your title, your $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]$ are "quadratic integer rings" only when $D \not\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. That phrase refers to the ring of integers of the quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$, which is a bit bigger than you'd naively expect when $D \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$.
- Norms are defined quite generally in field theory as the product of the Galois conjugates; e.g. [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm).
- That standard general definition of the norm $N \colon \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D}) \to \mathbb{Q}$ is simply $N(a+b\sqrt{D}) = a^2-Db^2$. Obviously when $D<0$ this restricts to $N \colon \mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{D}) \to \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, with $N(0) = 0$ and $N(a+b\sqrt{D}) > 0$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ not both zero.
- Most people typically use the general norm definition in this context without tossing out $0$ or using absolute values e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer#Euclidean_rings_of_quadratic_integers), [William Stein](https://www.wstein.org/edu/124/lectures/lecture20/lecture20/node3.html). However, when you're talking about whether the norm makes the ring of integers a Euclidean domain and $D>0$, the absolute value signs [become important](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Norm-Euclidean_fields).
- [Euclidean functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Definition) require the codomain to be $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ depending on your axiomatization. Restricting to a half-open interval is done to make sure the Euclidean algorithm terminates in finitely many steps, so that explains the absolute value signs.
- But why are Euclidean functions often left undefined at $0$? [See this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31681/euclidean-function-at-0) on the topic. The short answer is for, say, $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, we want to use $\deg$ as the Euclidean function, but $\deg(0) = -\infty$ is the best definition, which conflicts with requiring the codomain to be $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.